# How to properly use string indices to create a rot13 equivalent of a string

Tags: python, string, indexing, indices

For my programming class, we have to create a function that takes in a string argument and returns the rot13 equivalent of the string. When I try running my function, it says that count can't equal str[i] because string indices have to be integers. I'm honestly lost and what else I could do to make the function work. Any help would be lovely

```
def str_rot_13(str):
     new_list = []
     for i in str:
         if ord(i) <= 77:
             count = str[i]
             k = chr(ord(count) + 13)
             new_list.append(k)
         if ord(i) > 77 and ord(i) <= 90:
             count = str[i]
             k = ord(count) - 78
             new_list.append(chr(65 + k))
     return new_list
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `count = str[i]`?

Comment: @gommb To me, I think it makes it so that the function will go through every part of the string that I enter. Is this not a correct way to go through the string?

Comment: the `for i in str:` will make it go through every character in str.

Comment: just remove `count = str[i]` and replace wherever you use `count` with `i`

Comment: @gommb it's working now, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 for i in str:
     if ord(i) <= 77:
         count = str[i]
         k = chr(ord(count) + 13)
```

In Python, `for i in str` will loop through every character in the string `str`, with `i` set to that character (which you already know, since you're doing `ord(i)`). (Don't use `str` as a name, by the way: `str` is the Python name for [the string type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str#textseq).) `count = str[i]` is treating the character in `i` as an index. You don't need to (or should) do that. It doesn't make much sense.